# In breadth first search and depth first search why the visited array is initialized globally

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Visited array mean by the array where we keep records of whether a node is visited or not.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about a particular implementation. Those details need to be provided.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search   the algorithm is given here. i am new please dont downvote :/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Tree traversal is easy, provided the tree is well-formed. You do not have to keep track of whether you're potentially about to repeat some work in a possibly endless loop because there's exactly one path to reach each node.

But for *generalised* graph traversal where the graph may contain loops, many trivial algorithms will end up looping endlessly when they encounter a loop. To guarantee that such algorithms do terminate, we usually want to keep track of which nodes we've visited during the entire traversal and not re-explore a node we've already visited.

That's the purpose of the `visited` collection (whether that be an array, a set, etc is irrelevant). Alternatives may be for each node to have a visited flag which can be unset before traversal and set during traversal. That avoids the need for a global collection but imposes its own limitations (only a single traversal can occur at a time).

The `visited` collection doesn't need to be "global"<sup>1</sup> but does need to be in a common scope shared by all parts of each traversal.

---

<sup>1</sup>If it is "global" then, in whatever scope that has meaning, again only a single traversal at a time is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the visited array is initialized globally?

Since the array is used for keeping track of the *entire* graph, it is better to have a global/class level initialization.

Otherwise, in a method level initialization you would need to pass the tracking information (aka the `visited[]` array) by reference or make a new copy of it for every call to explore a node.

---

Further, if:

1. You were tracking something local to the current node; OR
2. The algorithm's implementation was not recursive;

you could do away with a local initialization too.